# Textview ellipsize text without dots and cutting last word

Tags: android, textview, ellipsize

I'm using android TextView with android:maxLines="1" and trying to use all types of ellipsize, but no one of them does not satisfies my requirements. I want to ellipsize text **without** adding dots at the and and **without** cutting whole last word. I want to cut just chars of last word without loosing whole word

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:maxLines="1"
/>
```

Comment: Soooo if you don't want to ellipsize your text just don't use ellipsize ;)

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii if i don't use ellipsize then whole last word cutting from phrase

Comment: Can't you use [Auto Sizing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)? if its an option . Other than that you can use `android:ellipsize="none"` it will cut the remaining characters without ellipsis .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need next property:

```
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="none"
```

Here us your xml:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    />
```